# Change compose View orientation

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I use this code to change composable View orientation but it doesn't work and I don't need to change app orientation

```
val configuration = Configuration()         
configuration.orientation = Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
CompositionLocalProvider(LocalConfiguration provides configuration) {
            Screen()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the screen orientation using this:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        startActivity(intent)

        setContent {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
            Text("I'm a cat person")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Johann  
This code change activity orientation
I need change Composable function

Comment: Did this solve your issue? If so, please mark my solution as accepted. Thanks!

Comment: no its not work